# Converting brush[] to string or brush[] to color[] to string

Tags: c#, string, colors, brush

I am not trying to convert brush to string, but brush array to string.

I need to write a txt file on xml and then I am trying to convert a `brush[]` into a `string`, but I do not know how to this directly.

So, I tried to convert first to `color` and then I would convert `color` to `string`.

I am struggling with the first conversion where the code is not allowing me to write this part:

```
Color[] cor1_local = new Pen(cor_local[i]).Color[];
```

`cor_local` is `brush[]`.

Code:

```
xml.WriteStartElement("cor_frmlocal");
for (int i = 0; i < cor_local.Length; i++)
{
    Color[] cor1_local = new Pen(cor_local[i]).Color[];
    xml.WriteElementString("Cor_local", cor1_local[i].ToArgb().ToString());
}
xml.WriteEndElement();
```

Comment: I would suggest [*serializing*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the colors and brushes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use that

```
        xml.WriteStartElement("cor_frmlocal");
        for (int i = 0; i < cor_local.Length; i++)
        {
            xml.WriteElementString("Cor_local", ((SolidBrush)cor_local[i]).Color.ToArgb().ToString());
        }
        xml.WriteEndElement();
```

the problem was in usage of base `Brush` class object references that do not contain Color property. To handle that you must cast it back to `SolidBrush`.

To convert brush back

1) create the list of brushes `var brushList = new List<Brush>();`

2) read color value as `var colorValue = Convert.ToInt32(reader.ReadElementString());`

3) create color from that value `var color = Color.FromArgb(colorValue);`

4) create new brush and add it to list `list.Add(new SolidBrush(color));`

the result code looks like

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(filename);
string node_info = "";
var brushList = new List<Brush>();

while(reader.Read())
{
    node_info = reader.Name;

    if (node_info == "cor_frmlocal")
    {
         var colorValue = Convert.ToInt32(reader.ReadElementString());
         var color = Color.FromArgb(colorValue);
         list.Add(new SolidBrush(color));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried to use it before, but it gets problem on the .Color

Comment: `ToArgb() ` method returns unsigned int value

Comment: 'System.Drawing.Brush' does not contain a definition for 'Color' and no extension method 'Color' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Drawing.Brush' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What kind of brush you have used?

Comment: If you using regular brush, it must work now.

Comment: I am using solidbrush.

I also tried:

            xml.WriteStartElement("cor_frmlocal");
            for (int i = 0; i < cor_local.Length; i++)
            {
                Color cor1_local = new Pen(cor_local[i]).Color;
                cor2_local[i] = cor1_local;

                xml.WriteElementString("Cor_local", cor2_local[i].ToArgb().ToString());

            }
            xml.WriteEndElement();

I got no errors back but while running, it stops on:

                cor2_local[i] = cor1_local;

Comment: Watch up to the code it must work now.

Comment: it worked fine! Thanks!! and what about the way back? I changed my code about how I am trying to convert from string to brush[].

Comment: do not forgot to vote + :)